# jqgrid - i want to add colModel dynamically. but ,jsonmap not working

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i want to add colModel dynamically. but, jsonmap not working.

this is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search_btn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Search/SearchButton",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    var search_word = $('#search_bar').val();
                    var baseLang = $('#baseLang_choice_single').val();
                    var targetLang = $('#targetLang_choice_multi').val();
                    var products = $('#product_choice_multi').val();
                    var columnNames = [];
                    var columnModels = [];
                    var languageLength;

                    var getVaueByName = function (cells, colName) {
                        var i, count = cells.length, item;
                        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
                            item = cells[i];
                            if (item.colname === colName) {
                                return item.value;
                            }
                        }
                        return '';
                    };

                    columnNames.push(baseLang);
                    if (targetLang == "") {
                        columnNames.push("yyy");
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < targetLang.length; ++i) {
                            columnNames.push(targetLang[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    columnNames.push('ID');
                    columnNames.push('Product');


                    columnModels.push({ name: 'languageGroup.0.Key', jsonmap: 'languageGroup.0.Value' }); //is that right?

                    if (targetLang == "") {
                        columnModels.push({ name: 'languageGroup.1.Key', jsonmap: function (obj) { return getVaueByName(obj.languageGroup, "yyy"); }, sortable: false }); //is that right?
                    }
                    else {
                        for (var i = 1; i <= targetLang.length; ++i) {
                            columnModels.push({ name: 'languageGroup.'+i+'Key', jsonmap: 'languageGroup.'+i+'Value', sortable: false }); //is that right?
                        }
                    }
                    columnModels.push({ name: 'ID', index: 'ID' });
                    columnModels.push({ name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 80, align: "center" });


                    $(function () {
                        jQuery("#search_datagrid").jqGrid("GridUnload").jqGrid({
                            url: '/Search/SearchDataGrid/',
                            datatype: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                            mtype: 'POST',
                            postData: {
                                search_word: search_word,
                                baseLang: baseLang,
                                targetLang: targetLang,
                                products: products
                            },
                            jsonReader:{
                                repeatitems: false,
                                root:"rows"
                            },
                            jsonmap: function (item) {
                                //return item.languageGroup.Key; ????? is that right?
                            },
                            rowNum: 20,
                            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
                            colNames: columnNames,
                            colModel: columnModels,
                            ..............

                            ............................}
```

controller code.

```
search.DosearchWord(....) return List< T >  (
     List< KeyValuePair< string,string > > languageGroup,
     String ID,
     String Product)

var json = search.DoSearchWord(search_word, baseLang, targetLang, products).ToList();
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = search.DoSearchWord(search_word,baseLang,targetLang,products).ToList().Count,
            rows = (
                new
                {
                    cell = json
                })
        };
        var jsonResult = Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
```

above json data here

```
[{"languageGroup":[{"Key":"yy","Value":"xx"},{"Key":"yyy","Value":"xxx"},{"Key":"yyyy","Value":"xxxx"},{"Key":"yyyyy","Value":"xxxxx"}],"stringID":"blahblah,"product":"blahblah"},{"languageGroup":[{"Key":"yy","Value":"xx"},{"Key":"yyy","Value":"xxx"},{"Key":"yyyy","Value":"xxxx"},{"Key":"yyyyy","Value":"xxxxx"}],"stringID":"blahblah,"product":"blahblah"}.....]
```

languageGroup length and name is dynamic

Comment: You included wrong JSON data. 1) there are unclosed quotes see `"stringID":"blahblah,"product":"blahblah"` instead of `"stringID":"blahblah","product":"blahblah"` 2) the JSON data don't correspond the server-side code. The server returns `{"total":1, "page":1, "records": xxx, "cell": [...] }` .  How many total rows could be displayed in the grid (100, 1000, 10000, 100000, ...)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Could you include an example of column headers, which you want to have?  The example of JSON data allows to have **different `Key` in every row** of data. Is `languageGroup[i].Key` the part of data or you have **the same values** in all items? You use `columnNames.push(targetLang[i])`, where `targetLang` is not the part of data returned from the server. It looks strange. Has `targetLang` some relation to `languageGroup[i].Key`? You use `jsonmap: 'languageGroup.'+i+'Value'` instead at least `jsonmap: 'languageGroup.'+i+'.Value'` (**with additional `.` before `Value`). `i` should starts with 0**